# Align buttons to bottom-left corner using flex

Tags: html, css

I need to align a div at the bottom-left corner of the parent div, just like the second example in this Bootstrap docs flex demo link: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#align-items

*The only difference in my case is that one of the child items is an image.* Alignment should happen regardless of screen size.

In the following example button-container div needs to align bottom-left of flex-container.

**EDIT:**
The button-container should appear on the image itself, not below the image.

```css
.flex-container{
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end !important;
  border: solid 1px red;
}

.button-container{
  border: solid 1px green;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
    <img src="https://www.webkit.org/blog-files/acid3-100.png" />
    <div class="button-container">
        <button>Button 1</button>
        <button>Button 2</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you missed in your code is `flex-direction`. By default it will be row, hence the div's were coming side by side. You need to specify the value as `column`.

```css
.flex-container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start !important;
  border: solid 1px red;
  position: relative;
}

.button-container{
  border: solid 1px green;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
    <img src="https://www.webkit.org/blog-files/acid3-100.png" />
    <div class="button-container">
        <button>Button 1</button>
        <button>Button 2</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: Made the buttons `position: absolute`. You can use the left/top properties as mentioned already in the snippet to align them as per your requirement.

Comment: Perfect. Can you please see my edit also?

Comment: Sure, u can use position absolute to make the buttons come above the image and use left/right/top/bottom properties to align them as required. Will update in the above snippet

Comment: Have updated my answer @joym8. can you verify

Comment: It's creating side by side divs.

Comment: Can you verify the snippet in my answer ?

Comment: Yes that's what I did, and also tried locally, same result. Click on "Expand Snippet" link and see yourself

Comment: No no, the image is right aligned, so that you may be seeing it as side by side. I will update the snippet

Comment: I updated the snippet with `flex-end` to `flex-start`. Check now

Answer (score 0):

If you know the dimensions of the image in advance I'd suggest using the background property

```css
.flex-container{
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end !important;
  border: solid 1px red;
  background-image: url("https://www.webkit.org/blog-files/acid3-100.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 780px;
  height: 619px;
}

.button-container{
  border: solid 1px green;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="button-container">
        <button>Button 1</button>
        <button>Button 2</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately setting background causes more issues in my case, because the image is a marketing image and has text on it. Any clipping due to shrinking/expanding screen size is not acceptable.